# SBT - Invoke GCC call failing in SBT, but not when I manually execute it

Tags: c, scala, gcc, sbt

I'm working on a library that is going to talk to the I2C bus on my Raspberry PI from Scala. For this I need a little bit of JNI code that is going to interrupt with the OS on the device.

I tried to make a build file for this, which right now, looks like this:

```
name := "core"

organization := "nl.fizzylogic.reactivepi"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"



val nativeClasses = List(
  "nl.fizzylogic.reactivepi.i2c.I2CDevice"
)

val nativeDeviceSources = List(
  "src/jni/nl_fizzylogic_reativepi_i2c_I2CDevice.c"
)

val nativeGenerateHeaders = taskKey[Int]("Generates JNI headers for the library")
val nativeCompile = taskKey[Int]("Compiles the native library")

nativeGenerateHeaders := {
  ("javah -classpath target/scala-2.11/classes -d src/jni " + nativeClasses.mkString(" ")) !
}

nativeCompile := {
  ("gcc -Wl -add-stdcall-alias -I$JAVA_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include/darwin -I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux -shared -o target/reactivepi.so " + nativeDeviceSources.mkString(" ")) !
}
```

So far the javah call is successful. But when I invoke the nativeCompile task, GCC tells me it can't find the jni.h file. However when I copy and paste the command from the build file to my terminal and execute it, it succeeds.

It looks like it is not picking up the include paths when I am executing gcc from my custom build task. But I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.